# This code works in my computer but not in leetcode

Tags: python, algorithm, python-2.7

I am trying to solve this [leetcode](https://leetcode.com/problems/replace-words/description/) problem. The output is fine when I run it in my laptop but not when I submit it to leetcode. Spent an hour and still couldn't figure out. Couple more eyes should surely help.

```
class Solution28(object):
def replaceWords(self, dict, sentence):
    """
    :type dict: List[str]
    :type sentence: str
    :rtype: str
    """
    dict=sorted(dict)
    slist=sentence.split(' ')
    #print slist
    n = len(slist)
    for i in xrange(n):
        for d in dict:
            if d in slist[i]:
                slist[i]=d
                break
            elif d > slist[i]:
                break
    return " ".join(slist)

obj = Solution28()
print obj.replaceWords(["cat", "bat", "rat"],"battery cattle was rattled by the battery")
####o/p from my laptop: bat cat was rat by the bat
####o/p in leetcode: battery cat was rat by the battery
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an algorithmic bug in this code when words are not at the start.

For example this code would consider that "rat" is a root of "mouserat".

However, if you change the line:

```
if d in slist[i]:
```

to

```
if slist[i].startswith(d):
```

it passes fine for me when I tested in leetcode.

Comment: I feel stupid. Thanks for the help